# Email Form first name capital

Tags: php, forms, capitalize

I am using dreamweaver and have a form on my page. I managed to collect details from the user and email them etc but would like it to have the punters name first letter in capital.

```
$MailSubject     = "".((isset($_POST["pename"]))?$_POST["pename"]:"")  ." Sent Email From space see Website.";
```

I have had a look around and have tried adding

ucfirst($foo);

but that didnt work.

can someone please advise me as to how to add the ucfirst to the mail subject variable.

thank you

Seemore

Comment: Why should `ucfist` not work? Please show us the exact code where you use `ucfist`.

Comment: Try **echo ucfirst($MailSubject);** and if not work try **error_reporting(E_ALL)**

Comment: And this works- 
$foo="bar";
echo ucfirst($foo);

Comment: $MailSubject     = "".ucfirst(((isset($_POST["pename"])))?$_POST["ename"]:"")  ." Sent Email From ding dong Company Website.";

Comment: thank you all. wow, as you can see i am not a good coder. anyway this got it working. thanks all very much and have a lovely weekend.  $MailSubject     = "".ucwords(((isset($_POST["pename"]))?$_POST["pename"]:"")) 
it was all the ((((( that got me so confused .